# Creating a HTML page with 5 Frames

Tags: html

I am trying to create a HTML Frame as seen in the image below. I will be creating a snapshot of the OS and the Server spaces [image: HTML 5 Pane Frames]

Request your help with this... I have tried iframes and am unable to get the setting right... The frames should occupy half the screens and the whole screen needs to be populated. It would be better if this can be scrollable and the frame borders movable in either directions.

The image below shows How I have designed it now... I just don't seem to get the px or % right.
[image: This shows how I have done it]

This is the code I have now: -

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="500" src = "menu.html"></iframe>
        <iframe width="500"></iframe>

        <br><br>

        <iframe width="500px"></iframe>
        <iframe width="500px"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking

Comment: Well, for starters you're going to need to write some actual HTML code instead of just using an image like that.  Are you just looking for tutorials on HTML, specifically on the use of frames?  There are many to be found on Google.

Comment: Simply try setting the `width` to `50%` instead of fixed `500px`. Then take the next step and organize your layout in a table or div. This is pretty basic stuff - if you don't want to hand-craft your layout, try using a wysiwyg editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/s2tgqt7m/1/

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #535353; float: left; width: 400px; height: 400px;">
    Processes running
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid #535353; float: left; width: 400px; height: 400px;">
    Processes stopped
</div>

<table style="width: 400px; float: left;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">Disc space</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Disk</td>
    <td>Label</td>
    <td>Size (GB)</td>
    <td>Used</td>
    <td>Free</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="width: 400px; float: left;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">Hot Fixes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td colspan="3">Link</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That would be a start... but nothing great! Before you do something like that you should consider to read up on some basic html layouting.

- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp
- https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Anwendung_und_Praxis/Layout_mit_Grid
- http://de.learnlayout.com/

Give it a try and if you get stuck come back here and ask for help.

Some keywords which will be helpful:

`colspan`: Merge cells in tables

`float`: The property specifies whether or not an element should float.

`div`, `iframe`, `embed`, `css layout`, `css grid`...

later in the process: `box-sizing`, `margin`, `padding` and `clear`

If you don't have to, try to avoid iFrames!

Cheers